# Retrain SVM classifier in OpencCV?

Tags: opencv, svm

I built a image classification system with SVM as a classifier. For my purpose, I've got quite good classification results, but I'm looking for a way to improve it. Suppose for a query image, the system responses with false classification. Is there any way to retrain SVM classifier with this new data. I use SVM from OpenCV. Do I need use different classifier or learning system?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different classifier, but a simple way to improve your existing system, would be to retrain your classifier using hard negatives. To do that:

- Using your original classifier on a training set with negative samples, find all false positives. These are the so called "hard negatives".
- Retrain your system, using the original training dataset, enhanced with the hard negatives you found in the previous step.
- You might get improved results if you repeat the previous steps once or twice.

The classifier you finally get should be better than the one you started with. Be careful not to get hard negatives from your testing dataset, because that will give you incorrect results.